# Python, tkinter buttons within tab not spacing with grid

Tags: python, tkinter

I attempting to design a "toolbox" or application/script launcher for quick script execution for our team. I landed on Python with tkinter to design the GUI.  I am inexperienced with GUI building and struggling to get the grid function to work within tkinter tabs.

Below is my code so far...

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text, ttk
import os

root  = tk.Tk()
root.title("IT Toolbox")
root.iconbitmap('//fs02/IT/Scripts/IT Toolbox/bs.ico')
root.minsize(600, 700)

#Define Functions
def adminpwsh():
os.startfile("C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe")
def fncmd():
os.startfile("C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe")

#Defines Tab Space
tabControl = ttk.Notebook (root)

#Define HOME tab
tabMain = ttk.Frame (tabControl)
tabControl.add (tabMain, text = 'Home')

btnPowershell = tk.Button(tabMain, text ="Powershell", bg='#0F861B', fg='#FFFFFF', font=12, padx=2,                 pady=2, command=adminpwsh)
btnPowershell.grid(column=1, row=4)

btnCommand = tk.Button(tabMain, text ="Command", bg='#0F861B', fg='#FFFFFF', font=12, padx=6, pady=2, command=fncmd)
btnCommand.grid(column=1, row=12)

grid_columnconfigure()

#Define tab2
TabAD = ttk.Frame (tabControl)
tabControl.add (TabAD, text = "tab2")


#Define tab3
TabWU = ttk.Frame (tabControl)
tabControl.add (TabWU, text = "tab3")

#Defines pack for all tabs
tabControl.pack(expan = 1, fill = "both")
```

Right now the buttons on the tab are all clustered in the top left of the tab and I cannot position them where I want within the tab.   Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have to allow the space between Row 4 and Row 12 to **grow**. Read up on [Tkinter.Grid.grid_rowconfigure-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_rowconfigure-method) and [When to use the Place Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text, ttk
import os

root  = tk.Tk()
root.title("IT Toolbox")
# root.iconbitmap('//fs02/IT/Scripts/IT Toolbox/bs.ico')
root.minsize(600, 500)

#Define Functions
def adminpwsh():
    os.startfile("C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe")
def fncmd():
    os.startfile("C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe")

#Defines Tab Space
tabControl = ttk.Notebook (root)

#Define HOME tab
tabMain = ttk.Frame (tabControl)
tabControl.add (tabMain, text = 'Home')

btnPowershell = tk.Button(tabMain, text ="Powershell", bg='#0F861B', fg='#FFFFFF', font=12, padx=2,                 pady=2, command=adminpwsh)
btnPowershell.grid(column=1, row=4)

btnCommand = tk.Button(tabMain, text ="Command", bg='#0F861B', fg='#FFFFFF', font=12, padx=6, pady=2, command=fncmd)
btnCommand.grid(column=1, row=12)

root.columnconfigure(0)

#Define tab2
TabAD = ttk.Frame (tabControl)
tabControl.add (TabAD, text = "tab2")


#Define tab3
TabWU = ttk.Frame (tabControl)
tabControl.add (TabWU, text = "tab3")

#Defines pack for all tabs
tabControl.pack(expan = 1, fill = "both")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you could take a look at this code I posted here about rowconfigure and columnconfigure https://pythonprogramming.altervista.org/tkinter-python-site-launcher/